# javax.servlet.ServletException: ICEfaces requires the PersistentFacesServlet

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces, jsf-1.2, icefaces-1.8

I am a beginner in ICEFACES, trying to run my first ICEFACES screen successfully using some ICEFACES components. To get started with. I am using ICEFACES 1.8.2.

I copied the content of my web.xml from this link:

http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v1_8_2/htmlguide/gettingstarted/SessionRendererTutorial11.html#1054095

Below is the faces-config.xml file:

```
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
version="1.2">
<application>
    <view-handler> 
    com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler 
    </view-handler>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

Below is the **Test.jsp** screen content:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="ice"  uri="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
    <ice:outputText id="txtHello" value="Hello ICEFaces"></ice:outputText> <br> 
    <ice:panelGroup title="Hello"></ice:panelGroup>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the app using the below URL:

`http://localhost:8046/TestMojarra/faces/Test.jsp`

I am getting an exception:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: ICEfaces requires the PersistentFacesServlet. Please check your web.xml servlet mappings
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)`

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: ICEfaces requires the PersistentFacesServlet. Please check your web.xml servlet mappings
    com.icesoft.faces.context.DOMResponseWriter.<init>(DOMResponseWriter.java:154)
    com.icesoft.faces.context.DOMContext.createTemporaryDOMResponseWriter(DOMContext.java:182)
    com.icesoft.faces.context.DOMContext.getDOMContext(DOMContext.java:228)
    com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:89)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:840)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
    com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
    com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:151)
    com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:151)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)`

But if I comment out the `<ice:panelGroup>` line from the above jsp file, the screen is getting displayed.

Kindly let me know where is the issue.

Comment: It looks like you're not using the PersistentFacesServlet, as specified at the start of that tutorial.  Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: Hmm, looking at the web.xml, jsp files won't be picked up by the PersistentFacesContext.  Try renaming the file to .jspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I rename it to `.jspx` then I am getting this exception: `java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /Test.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource` Not sure from where is this xhtml part comming :(

Comment: Try renaming to Test.xhtml?

Comment: I tried that also. In that case I am getting an exception: `error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name`. Kindly let me know how to make it work :( . Also let me know how to use in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all I ever did in my web.xml.  I had the servlet declarations

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And the the mappings to the servlets

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ifaces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/block/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I always used xhtml files, though, and not jsp files.  But, this always worked for me.

EDIT I've re-edited your sample into xhtml format.  There were two tags which weren't valid xhtml.  But this is what typically worked for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <f:view>
      <ice:outputText id="txtHello" value="Hello ICEFaces"></ice:outputText> <br/> 
      <ice:panelGroup title="Hello"></ice:panelGroup>
    </f:view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please post a sample xhtml file containing a outputText ans a ice:Panel component? I need to check a few things: 1) The beginning tags (i.e. lines present above the DOCTYPE) for an xhtml files 2) Let me know whether the web.xml is using v2.4 or 2.5 I feel like the problem is only with the version mismatch.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a xhtml-compliant version of the jsp page attached to this question.  The meta and br tags weren't valid xhtml, and I used the xml syntax of tag declaration

Comment: I tried it but not working :( Need some more info: 1) post the web.xml web-app version tag (the first two lines of your web.xml) 2) post the url you are using to trigger this simple demo application (i.e. file Tst.xhtml)

Comment: And what are the jars you are using? Are you deploying the app in Tomcat?

Comment: This is the first line of the web.xml: <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

Comment: This being deployed in Glassfish v2 (this was a year or so ago, and it is an older version of both ICEfaces and JSF).  The url was simply the the root url for the application.  I didn't need to go directly to the page.  I can't tell you what jars we're using (apart from glassfish 2), as I haven't worked actively on this application for some time now.

Comment: SOmehow I got it working...Imported the WAR files present in sample folder of the downloaded binary bundle and replicated the same in my workspace tomake it working :) Thanks for the help